# How to remove the clickevent of the Gridview in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with OnRowDataBound method to manually create dynamic divs in the cells within a column. I use .Attribute.Add("onmouseover","DisplayData( .... )") to add mouseover events on the cells.

At run time when one of the cells is mouseovered it invokes an AJAX function to retrieve data, which in turn populates the div inside the cell. That data contains hypelinks. The problem is, those hyperlinks are not clickable because they are overridden by the click event of the Gridview.

How can I remove the clickevent of the Gridview so it would not interfere with my AJAX-built hyperlinks within the divs that are inside the Gridview?

Comment: GridView doesn't have a Click event, are you handling RowCommand event?

Comment: Good point, thank you! I could not use RowCommand because the hyperlinks inside the Gridviews are client-side, generated by AJAX. So what I did was a workaround by using "onmousedown" client event to avoid conflict with the "onclick" that was set somewhere